# When checking the website on an IPAD AngularJS

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have developed a web application using AngularJS & PHP, it works fine on chrome & firefox but have issues loading on IE due to number of JS files, i will have to reduce them to make it work on IE.

When checking the website on an IPAD, all my "angular tags" are displayed like it is 
"{{item}}" , "{{d.bar}}" , "{{d.lol}}", {{title}}, {{description}}, {{ratings}} etc.

can anyone have any thoughts why it would display like that

Comment: That's a pretty clear sign that some JS in your application throws an error and stops execution. If you're on a Mac you can use remote Safari debugging to find out what's wrong, otherwise you can check out sth. like weinre: http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/Home.html

Comment: @m90 I am using Windows, and don't have access to a MAC to verify, do you think installing Safari will help? if not what would be alternative for windows users?

Comment: Remote debugging via Safari is only available on OS X machines (which is a pretty d*ck move if you ask me). Weinre is pretty straightforward to use though, there's also a hosted version that you can use if you don't want to do the setup yourself: http://debug.phonegap.com/

Comment: @m90, thank you for sharing the hosted version. i was able to get it runing but very strange thing its not showing any errors -- its displaying some Tags correctly but most of them are {{ }} . the debugger is not showing any error at all.

Answer (score 0):

It could be, that there is some JavaScript issue on iPad, which prevents angular from doing its work. If there is some Developer Console on the iPad which displays javascript errors, you can try to fix them.